# working with intents and activities, hiding and showing activities

Tags: android

I am developing an application which consist of 5 activities. I wanted that three activities from them should appear to user when he/she install the app first time, after installation and registering in the app remaining two activities should be shown and previous three activities should not be shown ever, how to do this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by saving a flag in SharedPreferences. So the next time that activity is called you can check if the flag is set or not and based on that show the activity.

Comment: ok,, but where should i place the SharedPreference & Intent statements in MainActivity.java, within onCreate() method or any other method??

Comment: If you liked the answer do mark it as a correct answer

Comment: May I ask you for a little more help in Fragment??

Answer (score 0):

In your MainActivity, code the following

```
private void startUpChecking() {
    try {

        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(PRIVATE_PREF, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int currentVersionNumber = 0;

        int savedVersionNumber = sharedPref.getInt(VERSION_KEY, 0);

        try {
            PackageInfo pi = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
            currentVersionNumber = pi.versionCode;
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }


        if (currentVersionNumber > savedVersionNumber) {
         //call your intents here and do call finish after startActivity(your intent)
        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
 }
```

This code will call your required intent whenever you provide an update to your application or if user is opening your app for the very first time.

Call startUpChecking() from onCreate()